# Azure DevOps: Why is my subscription not shown when creating a new service connection?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am using *Azure DevOps* with a *Microsoft Account* (@outlook.com). The same account is co-administrator of 3 different *Azure Subscriptions*.

I am trying to create a new *Service connection* from my *Azure DevOps Project* to my newest *Azure Subscription* (out of the 3).

When I:

1. Go to my project's *Project Settings* view and click on the *Service Connections* tab.
2. Click on the '*New service connection*' button.
3. Choose '*Azure Resource Manager*' for the connection type.
4. Choose '*Service Principal (automatic)*' authentication method.

I find that the drop-down list for *Subscription* is only showing my two older subscriptions and my newer subscription is missing, as shown here:

[image: New Azure service connection dialog]

**How can I get my third, newer, subscription to appear in the 'Subscription' list?**

I've tried the following without success:

- Made my *Microsoft Account* to be a 'Co-administrator' of the *Azure Subscription*.
- Gave my *Microsoft Account* the 'Owner' Role for the *Azure Subscription*.
- Added my *Microsoft Account* to the 'Global Administrators' group in *Azure Active Directory*.
- Set 'Guest users permissions are limited' to 'No' in the In my *Active Directory*'s *External collaboration settings*.

**UPDATE:** The subscription that's not shown in the list is currently a "free-tier" subscription whereas the 2 subscriptions that are shown are "pay-to-go". Could this be the reason for my problem?

Comment: two newer subscriptions are free tier?

Comment: @Sajeetharan thanks. There is one new subscription and yes, it is free-tier at the moment.

Comment: @Sajeetharan thanks but I don't see any direct reference to free-tier Azure subscriptions not being accessible to Azure DevOps...?

Comment: that's my guess, in order to check you need to create a support ticket and see

Comment: Opened a 'problem' in the Visual Studio Cpmmunity Forum for Azure DevOps: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/987084/why-is-my-subscription-not-shown-when-creating-a-n.html

Comment: For me, the existing subscription only appeared once I had created a new app in Azure Portal via 'App Services > Create New App Service'.

I had existing app services, but none of them had the framework version and platform that the DevOps pipeline was targeting. Once I had created a suitable App Service the subscription appeared in the list in the DevOps Pipeline dropdown. Didn't have to logout/login to to refresh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can finally see my Azure Subscription in the Subscription list. I'm not 100% sure which step I took is responsible for fixing the issue so I'll list 2 things that I did:

1. In the Azure Portal I created a new App Registration, this time having the "Supported account types" setting set to "Accounts in any organizational directory ... and personal Microsoft account ...":
   [image]
2. In PowerShell and using the [AzureAD](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureAD/2.0.2.76) module I reset the *Service Principal* *Key Credential*:

   a. Ran *PowerShell* (v5.1) "as Administrator".

   b. `Install-Module -Name AzureAD`

   c. `Connect-AzureAD -TenantId <tenant-id-from-the-app-registration-overview>`

   b. `New-AzureADServicePrincipalKeyCredential -ObjectId <object-id-from-the-managed-application-overview>`

PS - The Subscription's being in the free-tier seems to be irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT  I don't understand the solution. What app registration do I need to change the settings for? When creating a new service connection I don't have an app registration yet. Creating the service connection creates the app registration, but I'm unable to create the service connection because the subscription is not listed.

Comment: What is <object-id-from-the-managed-application-overview> in this context?

Comment: If you are using a newer version of Powershell (I have 7.2) you may need to run `Import-Module AzureAD` before `Connect-AzureAD` is recognized as a valid command.

Comment: @tymtam On the application overview page on the right side there is a link next to **Managed application in local directory** you can click on.  This will give you the objectId you need.

Comment: Only 1 solved for me

Comment: Nothing worked for me.  I only see subscriptions in ONE directory, never any others, no matter what I try.  So frustrating.

Answer (score 16):

This is what solved it for me:

1. Go to your MS Azure account.
2. Search and go to 'Tenant Properties'.
3. Click on Manage Security Defaults.
4. Turn these off

Comment: I'm using Azure free tier and had the same issue as @urig. This answer did the trick for me.

Comment: Same here but when I changed the setting I got a popup from Microsoft with a question what the reason was for turning it off. So they could improve functionality or something like that

Comment: Turning off ALL security features just for the subscription to show seems like a big risk for a small reward. It would be better to know which permissions need to change in order for this to work.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe this was necessary... I reenabled the security defaults after selecting my subscriptions. Also, subscriptions started showing even when the security default was reenabled.

Comment: Instructions could remove ambiguity and combine steps 1 and 2 into "In Azure Portal search for 'Tenant Properties'".

Answer (score 3):

You can try accessing DevOps in a private mode, it simply gets the existing subscription.

Comment: This solves a different problem - cookies.

Answer (score 2):

Not an exact answer to the OP's question, but I think it's related and maybe helpful to others. My issues was creating a new subscription and that subscription not showing up on the Subscriptions page.

1. Click on the "Directories + subscriptions" button in top right.
2. Open dropdown and ensure desired subscriptions are selected

[image]

3. Navigate to Subscriptions page and click on "Subscriptions == globalfilter" and selected desired subscriptions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See if you have a "default subscription filter" set on the Portal Settings page. Seems to add one by default.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by deleting an old app registration with an expired certificate. I'm not sure about the link between the two, maybe it forced a refresh somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If Azure Devops does not list your Azure suscription this is the way to get the verify working for the service connection and get a deployment ok:

[image: The desired result]

Do the steps described in this link:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/creating-azure-resource-manager-manual-service-%C3%A7i%C4%9Fdem-kadako%C4%9Flu

After that you can deploy sucessfully using that service connection.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35682620)

Answer (score 0):

In case your subscription is in another AD, following steps solved my problem
In Azure DevOps, I clicked on my profile, and then click on Switch Directory and select your Microsoft Entra ID and then you should be able to see your azure subscription.